# Pegar o valor da <tr> que o usuário clicou numa tabela dinâmica

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, table

Olá...

Estou com um problema a muitos dias e não consigo resolver.

A situação é a seguinte: tenho uma tabela que é criada dinamicamente a partir dos dados existentes no banco:

[image: Tela de Busca]

**Quando o usuário passa o mouse por cima de uma opção, ela é destacada:**

[image: Tela de busca com opcao selecionada]

Preciso que ao clicar em uma linha selecionada, eu pegue o valor correspondente à coluna **Nome**, e possa por exemplo colocar esse valor numa variável para tratamentos futuros.

O grande problema é que não entendo uma forma de fazer isso numa tabela que é dinâmica, ou seja, o seu conteúdo varia de acordo com os dados do que estão sendo retornados do banco.

**EU PRECISO DESSA VARIÁVEL EM PHP, POIS ENVIAREI O VALOR DELA PARA OUTRA PÁGINA**

Segue abaixo o código onde ocorrem todos os processos:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/bus-coor.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <title>Buscar Coordenador</title>
</head>
<body>
<form class="registro form" method="get">
    <fieldset><legend>BUSCAR COORDENADOR</legend>
        <label class="labels" for="cNomCoo">Nome </label>
        <input type="text" name="tNomCoo" id="cNomCoo">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" onclick="criarVariavel();" value="Buscar">
    </fieldset>
</form>
<script>
    function criarVariavel() {
        <?php
        $nome_coo = $_GET['tNomCoo'];
        ?>
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>

<?php
include ('configBD.php');

if(!empty($nome_coo)){ // se a varivel tiver valor
// cria a instrução SQL que vai selecionar os dados
    $query = ("SELECT idCoo, tNomCoo, tEma, tTel, tFun FROM coordenador WHERE tNomCoo LIKE '%".$nome_coo."%'");
// executa a query
    $dados = mysqli_query($conexao, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
// transforma os dados em um array
    $linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dados);
// calcula quantos dados retornaram
    $total = mysqli_num_rows($dados);
}
else { // se a varivel não tiver valor seleciona retorna todos os dados
// cria a instrução SQL que vai selecionar os dados
    $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM coordenador ");
// executa a query
    $dados = mysqli_query($conexao, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
// transforma os dados em um array
    $linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dados);
// calcula quantos dados retornaram
    $total = mysqli_num_rows($dados);
}
?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Resultado da Pesquisa</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<table style="font-weight: bolder; text-align: center">
        <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #5e5e5e; alignment: center; padding: 2px;">ID</td>
        <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #5e5e5e; alignment: center; padding: 2px; width: 30%; overflow: auto;">Nome</td>
        <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #5e5e5e; alignment: center; padding: 2px; width: 30%; overflow: auto;">E-mail</td>
        <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #5e5e5e; alignment: center; padding: 2px; width: 20%; overflow: auto;">Telefone</td>
        <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #5e5e5e; alignment: center; padding: 2px; width: 30%; overflow: auto;">Categoria Funcional</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php
// se o número de resultados for maior que zero, mostra os dados
if($total > 0) {
    // inicia o loop que vai mostrar todos os dados
    do {
        ?>
        <table style="border-spacing: 0px; text-align: center;">
            <tr style="cursor: pointer; border-radius: 3px;" onclick="selecionaLinha" onMouseOver="javascript:this.style.backgroundColor='#75ee83'" onMouseOut="javascript:this.style.backgroundColor=''">
                <td id="cNomCoo" class="celula" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #5e5e5e; alignment: center; padding: 7px;"><?=$linha['idCoo']?></td>
                <td class="celula" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #5e5e5e; padding: 2px; width: 30%; overflow: auto;"><?=$linha['tNomCoo']?></td>
                <td class="celula" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #5e5e5e; padding: 2px; width: 30%; overflow: auto;"><?=$linha['tEma']?></td>
                <td class="celula" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #5e5e5e; padding: 2px; width: 20%; overflow: auto;"><?=$linha['tTel']?></td>
                <td class="celula" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #5e5e5e; padding: 2px; width: 20%; overflow: auto;"><?=$linha['tFun']?>
            </tr>
            <br>
        </table>
        <?php
        // finaliza o loop que vai mostrar os dados
    }while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dados));
}// fim do if
?>
</body>
</html>
<?php
// tira o resultado da busca da memória
mysqli_free_result($dados);
?>
```

Comment: Mas você quer colocar o valor numa variavel javascript é isso ? É que na sua pergunta não vejo quase javascript nenhum e só vejo php quase.

Comment: Pode editar a pergunta esclarecendo se quer a variável em javascript ou php?

Comment: A variável tem que ser em PHP, pergunta editada, obrigado.

Comment: Jovem, "dinâmico" é quando vc altera um elemento ou vários elementos após a página ser renderizada, e isso é feito com JavaScript. Ou seja, sua tabela não é dinâmica porque ela já vem pronta do PHP.

Comment: Não tem como guardar um valor de um elemento para ser usado depois no PHP. O PHP roda no servidor e a página renderizada roda no navegador. O que vc pode fazer é usar Ajax e criar uma SESSION para guardar o valor e depois puxar via PHP. Ou então guardar esse valor num cookie via JavaScript e depois puxar pelo próprio JS.

Comment: Então se eu entendi bem esse código serviria por exemplo somente para uma consulta no banco de dados, como é uma das funções dele, uma visualização do que tem no banco, e para mim pegar o valor de alguma linha dessa eu teria que usar Ajax criando uma SESSION?

Peço desculpa, pois sou iniciante em linguagem web por isso minhas dúvidas parecem tão elementares.

Comment: @CarlosEduardoSilva Você pode passar o um valor para outra página através de um parâmetro na URL.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr a questão é como rsrs

Comment: Pesquisa como usar Javascript, especificamente manipulação do DOM, é simples, é só colocar um evento onClick, na linha que deseja, e dizer ao JS o que fazer quando clicar. Ou forma é utilizar GET e enviar para a outra página se for em PHP por exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

> "Preciso que ao clicar em uma linha selecionada, eu pegue o valor
>   correspondente à coluna Nome, e possa por exemplo colocar esse valor
>   numa variável para tratamentos futuros."

**Pegando o valor do idCoo e levando a uma variável $resultado no lado servidor do php para execução no momento do click, e vamos lear também para uma variável que pode ser reutilizada posteriormente (session)**

> Vamos dividir em dois arquivos, o primeiro (que você está trabalhando)
>   e o segundo que é o php onde vai salvar a variável com o conteúdo.
>
> No primeiro arquivo:

**Antes do código da tabela, coloque isto:**

```
<script>
function pegacampo_ajax($val) {
 var dado = $('#idCooDiv'+$val).html(); //pega o texto do div pelo id
 var link = "pegacampo_ajax.php"; //endereco do segundo arquivo php
 $.ajax({type: 'POST', url: link, data: dado, processData: false, contentType: false }).done(function (result) {
 $('#resultado').html(result);
 $('#resultado').css('display', 'block');
});
  return false;
}
</script>
```

**Edite esta parte na sua tabela:**

```
<td id="cNomCoo">
 <div style="height:50px;width:100px;color:red;font-weight:600;" onclick="pegacampo_ajax('idCooDiv<?=$linha['idCoo']?>')" id="idCooDiv<?=$linha['idCoo']?>">
  <?=$linha['idCoo']?>
 </div>
</td>
```

**Mostra o resultado (coloque em baixo da tabela):**

```
<div id="resultado" style="color:red;font-weight:600;width:100px;height:50px;"></div>
```

No segundo arquivo, com o nome de pegacampo_ajax.php

**Nele você escreve:**

```
<?php
function pegacampo_ajax(){
if (isset($_POST['dado'])){
$resultado = "$_POST['dado']";

//nesta linha tu pode salvar o dado numa session do php
//vou deixar em branco para voce fazer

}
else{
$resultado = "Não há conteúdo";
}
return $resultado;
}

$resultado = pegacampo_ajax();
echo $resultado;

?>
```

> O grande problema é que não entendo uma forma de fazer isso numa
>   tabela que é dinâmica, ou seja, o seu conteúdo varia de acordo com os
>   dados do que estão sendo retornados do banco

Prontinho, se não entender assim pede para alguém editar minha resposta pra voce com o código final, mas este já é em vez de pegar o nome, pega o id.

**Não executei, pode ter erro**

Pra mudar é só trocar o texto que estiver dentro do div e o valor vai mudar, pode usar para o nome, ou o que quiser

**O pulo do gato é concatenar o id que vem do banco com o id da div para ficar único**

Eu concatenei o id que vem do banco de dados junto com o id do div, fazendo com que ele fique unico, e então, tu ao clicar, leva o valor dele via ajax, sem repetir, pois o nome fica id="nome+id", o id sempre diferente.